# How to return the closest time slots grouped by an entity, but just for one closest available day, not every available day?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that stores available appointments for a teacher, hourly based, with total freedom to add unlimited slots per day per teacher (as long as slots don't overlap). Example simplified structure:

```
CREATE TABLE time_slots (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  teacher_id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  slot bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 );
```

The **slot** column stores the timestamp of the slot.

How can I show all available slots for the first closest available day for every teacher?
Notice: show all time slots of a given day and can't show more than one day for the same teacher.

### Example data:

PS: using datetime just to make things more readable.

```
+----+------------+------------------+
| id | teacher_id | slot             |
+----+------------+------------------+
| 1  | 1          | 2013-04-10 08:00 |
| 2  | 1          | 2013-04-10 09:00 |
| 3  | 1          | 2013-04-10 09:30 |
| 4  | 1          | 2013-04-11 08:00 |
| 5  | 1          | 2013-04-11 09:00 |
| 6  | 1          | 2013-04-11 10:30 |
| 7  | 2          | 2013-04-12 07:00 |
| 8  | 2          | 2013-04-12 09:00 |
| 9  | 2          | 2013-04-14 08:00 |
+----+------------+------------------+
```

### Expected result:

Assuming a search is made on: **2013-04-10 08:30**, the returned results have to be:

```
+----+------------+------------------+
| id | teacher_id | slot             |
+----+------------+------------------+
| 2  | 1          | 2013-04-10 09:00 |
| 3  | 1          | 2013-04-10 09:30 |
| 7  | 2          | 2013-04-12 07:00 |
| 8  | 2          | 2013-04-12 09:00 |
+----+------------+------------------+
```

1. Don't show id 1 because it is already past 08:00 from day 10/Apr.
2. Don't show id 4, 5, 6 because we found the closest available slots for teacher = 1 to be id's 2 and 3.
3. Don't show id 9 because for teacher = 2 the closest available slots are the 7 and 8, so don't return another day.

### What I tried

I'm failing hard to come with a query, I just came with this basic query, but it makes no assumptions on getting just the 1st available day, and of course it doesn't return all available slots in a given day. It just returns 1 slot per teacher:

```
SELECT id, teacher_id, FROM_UNIXTIME(slot)
FROM time_slots
WHERE slot >= [Actual timestamp]
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(slot))
ORDER BY slot, teacher_id ASC
```

Note: I'm using FROM_UNIXTIME here just for purposes of debugging, of course I'll optimise indexes, etc later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a query to get the closest **day** for each teacher, since this will be different for each teacher. Some psuedo-ish SQL to do so here:

```
SELECT
  MIN(DATE(slot)) as closestDay,
  teacher_id
FROM time_slots
WHERE slot >= NOW()
GROUP BY teacher_id
```

Then take that query and use the results to show all available slots for each day

```
SELECT 
   id,
   time_slots.teacher_id,
   FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP(slot)
FROM time_slots
JOIN (
    SELECT
      MIN(DATE(slot)) as closestDay,
      teacher_id
    FROM time_slots
    WHERE slot >= NOW()
    GROUP BY teacher_id
) a
ON a.teacher_id = time_slots.teacher_id
  AND DATE(time_slots.slot) = closestDay
WHERE time_slots.slot >= NOW()
```

It's obviously not tested but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: @fthiella Thanks for the fiddle, I'm glad it worked. The `DAY` function probably isn't a long term solution when multiple months come in to play. I have edited my answer to use `DATE` instead.

Comment: @fthiella I will also mark this in my calendar as the first time I have ever written something that worked without testing it before

Comment: It's working amazingly good. I'll just switch from timestamp to datetime, so I can reduce a little overhead from the date functions (the slots table has 4M+ rows). Thanks!

Comment: Table has actually 7.7M records and it runs really fast. The problem is that I have another situation involved, and with an UNION it is going on by around 300ms. Do you have any idea of what could I do? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39748/individual-queries-run-on-10ms-with-union-all-they-are-taking-290ms-7-7m-reco

Answer (score 1):

No need for a join:

```
drop table if exists time_slots;
CREATE TABLE time_slots (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  teacher_id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  slot datetime 
 );
insert into time_slots values 
('1','1','2013-04-10 08:00'),
('2','1','2013-04-10 09:00'),
('3','1','2013-04-10 09:30'),
('4','1','2013-04-11 08:00'),
('5','1','2013-04-11 09:00'),
('6','1','2013-04-11 10:30'),
('7','2','2013-04-12 07:00'),
('8','2','2013-04-12 09:00'),
('9','2','2013-04-14 08:00');

select * from time_slots 
where (teacher_id, date(slot)) in
(select teacher_id, date(min(slot)) from time_slots where slot >= '2013-04-10 08:30' group by teacher_id)
having slot >= '2013-04-10 08:30'
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I made a bunch of tests with my actual data (7.7M rows) and the query proposed by @mattedgod with the Join runs an average of 30ms faster than yours (I tried sorting indexes, etc and his query was always the winner).